# How can i get the last item of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects. I need to render an information from the last item of the array and I try this:

```
<p>{leg.segments[leg.segments.length - 1].arrivalCity.caption},&nbsp;</p>
```

but it keeps giving an error

> Cannot read property 'caption' of undefined.

It seems that I can get items from arrays with length of 2 and more (or when specifically get `leg.segments[0].arrivalCity.caption` but get an error when try to render array with only one item. I can't understand what the problem is since it should just return `leg.segments[leg.segment[0]]` when array has just one item and be fine with it.

All objects have 'caption'-key, the only question is to get it from [0] or [1] index.

The array is a part of parsed JSON, here's one element I map through for an example:

```
"legs" :
 [
   {
     "segments" :
       [
         {
           "arrivalCity" :
             {
               "uid" : "LED",
               "caption" : "ST PETERSBURG"
             }
         },
         {
           "arrivalCity" :
             {
               "uid" : "LON",
               "caption" : "LONDON"
             }
         }
       ]
    },
    {
       "segments" :
         [
           {
              "arrivalCity" :
                {
                  "uid" : "MOW",
                  "caption" : "MOSCOW"
                }
           }
         ]
     }
 ]
```

I need to render LONDON in the first case and MOSCOW in the second. But I can get ST PETERSBURG and MOSCOW with `<p>{leg.segments[0].arrivalCity.caption}</p>` or an error with `<p>{leg.segments[leg.segments.length - 1].arrivalCity.caption}</p>`

Comment: can you please show your array?

Comment: done, edited the post!

Comment: @chris ... The misunderstanding might be due to ***not treating `legs` like an array***. Have a look at the answer.

Comment: @chris have a look Peter Seliger answer below. There is nothing wrong with the JSON object that you have posted in the question. You will get what you expect if you iterate correctly and get the relevant "leg" object out of "legs" array before look for the "arrivalCity" in last "segment" of the "segments" array.

Answer (score 1):

It is unable to reproduce your problem. Please show us your array.

Assuming your array is,

```
var leg={segments:[{arrivalCity:{caption:"cap1"}}]};
```

Then if you run;

```
leg.segments[leg.segments.length - 1].arrivalCity.caption
```

You will see the expected output as 'cap1'

Comment: @chris have a look Peter Seliger answer below. There is nothing wrong with the JSON object that you have posted in the question. You will get what you expect if you iterate correctly and get the relevant "leg" object out of "legs" array before look for the "arrivalCity" in last "segment" of the "segments" array.

Answer (score 1):

... quoting the OP ...

> *... `<p>{leg.segments[0].arrivalCity.caption}</p>` or ... `<p>{leg.segments[leg.segments.length - 1].arrivalCity.caption}</p>`*

The misunderstanding might be due to ***not treating `legs` like an array***. Thus, in order to always access the last `arrivalCity` item of each of a `segments` array, one has to iterate the `legs` array in first place.

Using the OP's sample data and implementing a basic render function which does iterate the `legs` array first and only with each iteration does access always the last item of the current `segments` array via e.g `segmentList[segmentList.length - 1]`, as already done correctly by the OP, nothing will fail but the expected result will render ...

- LONDON
- MOSCOW

... example ...

```js
function renderListOfLastArrivalCities(dataList) {
  const listNode = document.querySelector('.last-arrivals');

  dataList.forEach(({ segments: segmentList }) => {

  //const lastSegmentItem = segmentList[segmentList.length - 1];
  //const arrivalCity = lastSegmentItem && lastSegmentItem.arrivalCity;

    const arrivalCity = segmentList[segmentList.length - 1]?.arrivalCity;
    if (arrivalCity) {

      const itemNode = document.createElement('li');
      itemNode.textContent = arrivalCity.caption || '';

      listNode.appendChild(itemNode);
    }
  })
}

const legs = [{

  "segments": [{
    "arrivalCity": {
      "uid":"LED",
      "caption":"ST PETERSBURG"
    }
  }, {
    "arrivalCity": {
      "uid":"LON",
      "caption":"LONDON"
    }
  }]

}, {

  "segments": [{
    "arrivalCity": {
      "uid":"MOW",
      "caption":"MOSCOW"
    }
  }]

}];

renderListOfLastArrivalCities(legs);
```

```html
<ul class="last-arrivals"></ul>
```

Comment: No, by 'here's one element I map through for an example' I meant that I loop through a legs-array in the first place. That's why it's {leg.segments[0]... in my example, not {legs.segments[0]... Also it works out the same when I try work with only one element of legs and do legs[0].segments[legs[0].segments.length - 1] and breaks every time segments has only one element.

Comment: @chris ... you need to debug either your original data structure and/or your code because with the example you did provide everything works as smooth as can be. E.g with the `legs` array from the above example, accessing the last (and only) arrival city item via `legs[1].segments[legs[1].segments.length - 1]` returns `{ arrivalCity: {uid: "MOW", caption: "MOSCOW"} }` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `leg.segments[leg.segments.length - 1]` which i assume be as object that doesn't have **arrivalCity** property. If it has then you must be doing any typo or maybe your data shape is different.

Could you share your array with us to take a look over it.